# HTML Text writer

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project , i have created a custom control which inherits from label.
My aim is to add 2 links in this . I need to use the same label to render these two links.i tried the bellow code  only the first link is loading ,not the second .Please  help

my sample code looks like

```
writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Link);
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, string.Concat(Path 1));
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text/css");
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Rel, "stylesheet");
writer.RenderEndTag();

writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Link);
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, string.Concat(Path 2 ));
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text/css");
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Rel, "stylesheet");
writer.RenderEndTag();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the attributes before you render the html tag. The attributes you define for the first link in your code is actually being assigned to the second link tag. The first link tag remains empty.

```
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, string.Concat(Path 1));
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text/css");
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Rel, "stylesheet");
writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Link);

writer.RenderEndTag();

writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, string.Concat(Path 2 ));
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text/css");
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Rel, "stylesheet");
writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Link);

writer.RenderEndTag();
```

Comment: @George Zacharia, if this answer worked for you you should mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are code for you.

```
public class MyLabel : Label
{

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.InitLinkButton();
            base.OnInit(e);       

        }
    public void InitLinkButton()
    {
       System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div=new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
       HyperLink lnk = new HyperLink();
           lnk.NavigateUrl = "http://www.abc.com";
           lnk.Text = "Click here to go to abc.com";
           div.Controls.Add(lnk);  
           //same way you add more link to div
       //finally adding this to base control.
       base.Controls.Add(div);

    }

}
```